# NullPointerException when installing Maven project

Tags: rest, maven, microservices

Anytime I try and install my maven project, everything runs fine until I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:check (defau
lt) on project ecm-cif-adapter: Error while checking code coverage: null: EOFExc
eption -> [Help 1]
```

I also get this exception:

```
2020-05-25 08:45:19.659  WARN [spring,,,] 12504 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.w.c.s.
GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at ie.aib.msf.tomcat.customizer.GracefulShutdown.onApplicationEvent(Grac
efulShutdown.java:32)
        at ie.aib.msf.tomcat.customizer.GracefulShutdown.onApplicationEvent(Grac
efulShutdown.java:13)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.d
oInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.i
nvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.m
ulticastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publis
hEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publis
hEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClos
e(AbstractApplicationContext.java:992)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$2.run(
AbstractApplicationContext.java:929)
```

I have no idea how I'm supposed to use this information to diagnose the problem. The erros don't point me in any direction. There doesn't seem to be much help around the internet for this error

This is my pom.xml:

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>aaa</groupId>
  <artifactId>bbb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>aaa</name>
  <description>/description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>msf</groupId>
    <artifactId>msf-boot-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xmlbeam</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlprojector</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.4.6</version> -->
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProperties>
                        <msf-version>1.6.0</msf-version>
                        <spring-boot-version>1.5.20.RELEASE</spring-boot-version>
                    </additionalProperties>
                    <executable>false</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>validate</id>
            <activation>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireReleaseDeps>
                                    <message>No Snapshots Allowed!</message>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>org.apache.maven:maven-core</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org.apache.maven.plugins:*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </requireReleaseDeps>
                            </rules>
                            <fail>true</fail>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: Which version of spring do you use? Are you using a spring boot parent? Cause your pom snippet does not show?

Comment: I updated the question there. This is for my job so I'm just trying to be careful with what I share online

Comment: Unfortunately you have not answered the question...Apart from that the defined enforcer rules does not make sense in a usual project in a corporate environment such things should be handled by the parent.